# Detect retina (HD) display using PHP (server-side)

Tags: javascript, php, web, server-side

Is there a way to detect if the device has a Retina display using PHP not JavaScript?
I would like to deliver a different image according to the screen.

Comment: Post what you have tried?

Comment: @Bulat why did you mark it as a duplocate? You have added duplicate answer for javascript solution, when the question is actually asked about php solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing with the combination of JS, PHP and Cookies.

Try the below code and check whether it's useful for you.

```
<?php
if( isset($_COOKIE["device_pixel_ratio"]) ){
    $is_retina = ( $_COOKIE["device_pixel_ratio"] >= 2 );

    if( $is_retina)
        $thumbnail = get_image( $item_photo, 'thumbnail_retina' ) ;
    else
        $thumbnail = get_image( $item_photo, 'thumbnail' ) ;

}else{
?>
 <script language="javascript">
 (function(){
  if( document.cookie.indexOf('device_pixel_ratio') == -1
  && 'devicePixelRatio' in window
  && window.devicePixelRatio == 2 ){

   var date = new Date();
   date.setTime( date.getTime() + 3600000 );

   document.cookie = 'device_pixel_ratio=' + window.devicePixelRatio + ';' +  ' expires=' + date.toUTCString() +'; path=/';
  //if cookies are not blocked, reload the page
   if(document.cookie.indexOf('device_pixel_ratio') != -1) {
    window.location.reload();
  }
 }
})();
 </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

in function.php :

```
 add_action( 'init', 'CJG_retina' );

function CJG_retina(){
global $is_retina;  
$is_retina = isset( $_COOKIE["device_pixel_ratio"] ) AND $_COOKIE["device_pixel_ratio"] >= 2;
 }
```

Then after use the following GLOBAL:

```
global $is_retina; or $GLOBALS['is_retina'];
```